# Heroku development environment + git pain

Tags: php, git, heroku

I've read the docs on Heroku and managing multiple environments and I have a staging environment, and production environment on heroku.

However what's jamming me up is every time I want to deploy my code to my Heroku staging server, it makes a new commit.

Now my git repo is a mess. 'Typo' is the last 20 commit messages.

Is there a better workflow to reduce the amount of git commits? How have others kept their repos clean?

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of what you are doing to really provide much advice.  I have no idea what you're actually doing from the above text. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're constantly committing typos all in a row and not actual features, you can simply amend the previous commit so you they are fewer/sparse. The only caveat is that you'll have to force push to heroku as changing the commit history can be destructive.

```
git commit --amend
git push -f heroku master
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Basically squashing all the commits into one until its ready to go to production

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local repo, you can commit to THAT (which you should be doing). Only once you're done editing files on your LOCAL REPO, then you can PUSH to your staging repo.

Your staging repo will also have the same commits as your local repo.

From your staging repo, you can then either PUSH to your production, or from your production, PULL from your staging.

Please let me know if I've misunderstood your question, however.